# Python CD annual precentage

Tags: python

I am doing this assignment. when i input the number of months it is one printing one month. rather it be 5 months or 17 months its only printing 1 months total.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_K2RFTege5uZ2M5cWFuaGVvMzA/view?usp=sharing

Here is what i have so far what am i over looking thank you

```
calc = input('Enter y or n to calculate your CDs worth?')
month= int(input('Select your number of months'))
while calc == 'y':
    while month > 0:
        amount = int(input('Please enter the amount:'))
        percent= float(input('Please enter the annual percentage:'))
        calc= amount + amount* percent/ 1200
        print(calc)
```

Comment: Why do you use while loops? What is the question?

Comment: when i input the number of months it is one printing one month. rather it be 5 months or 17 months its only printing 1 months total.

Comment: @heinst I apologize i forgot to type my issue i was having here i'm new to the site. I am only having one issue not trying to have the whole assignment done for me...

Comment: So you're saying that when you enter the number of months, its no printing out the number you entered? @JeremyHarris

Comment: @JeremyHarris I understand what you were having trouble with...see my answer

Comment: @heinst i have another issue you think you could help me with? its on a different file.

Comment: @heinst

here is the link to it on here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749237/im-getting-a-traceback-error-that-im-not-understanding-why-its-happening/31749400#31749400

Comment: @JeremyHarris looks like you already got an answer?

Comment: @heinst
i did what they said do. But now Lets say i run this. i input up and 5 steps 
its outputting [0, 0, 5]

i need it output [0,5] 

we're trying to figure out how to replace the y-axis 0 with a 5 so it'll be 0,5. instead of adding on an  0 and printing 0, 0, 5.
 i hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use a `for` loop rather than while in this sense since you are doing a set amount of operations. You also were reusing calc and assigning calc to from a `String` to a `float`, generally a bad idea. The main problem is the formula builds upon the previously calculated number, it starts off with the initial amount entered, `10000 + 10000 * 5.75 / 1200 = 10047.91`, then uses `10047.91` in the next calculation, instead of `10000`, you never were reusing the previously calculated number, so you weren't getting the right answer. This should do it:

```
calc = input('Enter y or n to calculate your CDs worth?')
if calc == 'y':
    month = int(input('Select your number of months'))
    amount = int(input('Please enter the amount:'))
    percent = float(input('Please enter the annual percentage:'))
    for i in range(month):
        if i == 0:
            calcAmount = amount + ((amount * percent) / 1200)
        else:
            calcAmount = calcAmount + ((calcAmount * percent) / 1200)
        print calcAmount
```

Comment: with raw_input i remember reading something about in the newer python that raw_input was renamed to just input() is that correct

Comment: @JeremyHarris Yeah, I use python 2.7, so I use raw_input, but I updated my answer a few seconds ago so it should be correct now...sorry about that

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help... Sorry again if I came off as trying to get my whole assignment done on here! Not my intentions!

Comment: @JeremyHarris Don't sweat it! You fixed it by editing your question!